# How to not get errors accessing DateTime? properties in .NET with continue?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a loop that iterates over nullable `DateTime`s, `continue`s the loop if they are null or uses their Year and Month attributes if not.

This is a simplified example:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var dateTimes = GetDateTimes();
    
    foreach (var dateTime in dateTimes)
    {
        if (dateTime is null)
            continue;
        
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Year.ToString(), dateTime.Month.ToString());
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<DateTime?> GetDateTimes()
{
    return new List<DateTime?> { new DateTime(2021, 03, 22), null, DateTime.Now };
}
```

However, C# doesn't seem to be able to tell that, after the if-continue, the dateTime item is not null, and doesn't allow me to access its properties.

Even with an `if (dateTime != null)` it still complains?

Is there a way to make C# acknowledge the correct type, preferably with the `if-continue` structure?

The project uses .NET Core 3.1.

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lGYDd6)

Comment: Have you tried `dateTime.Value.Year.ToString()`?

Comment: You can't access the properties of a nullable value type like `DateTime?` directly.  You need to access its `Value` first.  Something like: `Console.WriteLine($"Year: {dateTime.Value.Year}  Month: {dateTime.Value.Month}");` Pro tip: include the error message an location the next time

Comment: `DateTime?` is a distinct type from `DateTime`. You'll need to explicitly convert it at some point, for example with `if (optionalDateTime is DateTime dateTime) { Console.WriteLine(...); }` among other approaches (inverting the condition, using a `.Where` and `.Select`, using `dateTime.Value`, etcetera).

Comment: Your code is wrong there. First "is" is for type checking it should be if (dateTime == null) or (!dateTime.HasValue). Second in your Console.WriteLine you should use dateTime.Value.Year ...

Comment: @CetinBasoz: in recent versions of C# `is` also supports pattern matching and `is null` (and `is not null`) are ways of comparing with `null` that are guaranteed to not invoke any user-defined equality operations.

Comment: @JeroenMostert but as you said, it is version dependent. He is saying core, which means this is cross platform and AFAIK on mono only up to 7.x exist, no?

Comment: You guys are correct. I was used to using GetValueOrDefault but forgot about this step. Using dateTime.Value after the if-continue also worked.

Comment: Is there a way to mark this as solved without posting an answer?

Comment: I would suggest using HasValue instead of is null.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: No. First of all, Mono and .NET Core are different platforms (as in, different runtimes) and the C# version associated with .NET Core 3.1 is C# 8, which supports pattern-matching `is`. Second, even if the question was about Mono somehow (which it's not), Mono 6 supports C# 8.

Comment: @Asghwor - You can self-answer with your solution if nobody else does it, although there is a waiting period before you will be able to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dateTime.GetValueOrDefault` or `dateTime.Value` solved the issue.